# What is the difference between a positive and negative space?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, luatex

I tried to find the relevant material on this but still failed to have a good one. What is the difference in nature between a positive and negative space? Are there any definitions for both in latex specification? I put the `\medspace` and `\negmedspace` but only to find that the latter is a bit thinner than the former.

Comment: a positive space moves things further apart a negative space moves them closer togther.  compare `xy`  with `x\hspace{5pt}y` and `x\hspace{-5pt}y`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A positive space moves things further apart moving later text to the right. A negative space moves them closer togther, moving later text to the left.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Compare:

xy with x\hspace{5pt}y and x\hspace{-5pt}y

\end{document}
```

You comment that you tried `\medspace`. In math mode that adds `\medmuskip` but LaTeX and plain TeX give `\medmuskip` a slighly curious default value of

```
\medmuskip=4mu plus 2mu minus 4mu
```

which means that in tight lines it may shrink to 0pt when of course negating it makes no difference.

You see here that in tight cases there is not so much difference, but in loose cases when `\medmuskip`can over-stretch the negative space moves y to the left almost off the page.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Natural size

[$xy$]  \rule{8cm}{1pt}

[$x\medspace y$]  \rule{8cm}{1pt}

[$x\negmedspace y$] \rule{8cm}{1pt}


\bigskip
Loose

[$xy$]  \rule{9cm}{1pt}\linebreak \mbox{}

[$x\medspace y$]  \rule{9cm}{1pt}\linebreak \mbox{}

[$x\negmedspace y$] \rule{9cm}{1pt}\linebreak \mbox{}



\bigskip
Tight

[$xy$]  \rule{10.95cm}{1pt}

[$x\medspace y$]  \rule{10.95cm}{1pt}

[$x\negmedspace y$] \rule{10.95cm}{1pt}



\end{document}
```